# Swift update programmed constraint

Tags: ios, swift

I have an interface with programmic constraints in Swift and I want to update them when the orientation of the device changes. This is how I set the width constraint:

```
    view.addSubview(comicImage)
    comicImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    comicImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true
```

This is my changeOrientation function

```
    private func changeOrientation() {
    if UIScreen.main.bounds.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.height {
       print("landscape")
        comicImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400.0).isActive = true
        comicImage.updateConstraints()
    } else {
        print("portrait")
        comicImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true
        comicImage.updateConstraints()
    }
}
```

This is how I call change orientation

```
   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    changeOrientation()
}
```

The function works, it prints out correctly when I rotate the phone, but I get an error saying I have two conflicting constraints. Do I have to remove one before I update it? How do I remove it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you call `changeOrientation()`?

Comment: Use `if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {} else {}`

Comment: You are continually adding new constraints.  You need to keep a reference to the original constraint you add and modify its `constant`.  Rather than using two fixed widths you should see if you can use an aspect ratio constraint between your view width and your sub view width.  Then your layout will adapt to rotation and different devices sizes automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ***adding a new constraint*** every time `changeOrientation()` is called -- it does not ***replace*** an existing constraint.

While your approach of setting an explicit width value and checking device orientation is a bad approach, you can see the proper way to update a constraint in this simple example:

```
class SimpleViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let comicImage = UIImageView()
    
    var comicWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // any normal setup / add views / etc stuff you are doing...
        
        comicImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        comicImage.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(comicImage)
        
        // always respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // create the width constraint
        comicWidthConstraint = comicImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400.0)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            comicImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            comicImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            comicImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),

            // activate the width constraint
            comicWidthConstraint,
        ])
        
    }
    
    private func changeOrientation() {
        if UIScreen.main.bounds.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.height {
            print("landscape")
            comicWidthConstraint.constant = 400.0
        } else {
            print("portrait")
            comicWidthConstraint.constant = 200.0
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        changeOrientation()
    }
}
```

It would serve you well to go through a bunch of auto-layout tutorials, guides, exercises, documentation, etc.

Comment: Thanks. The tutorials I used didn't address NSLayoutConstraint way of doing this. This is helpful. I like this better. thanks for your comment about safe area.